# How to do I obtain root privilege by an app running as system-uid?

Tags: android

I've set `sharedUserId` as "android.ui.system" in manifest and gotten it to run as system(uid), so now the apk has system privileges.

What should I do if I want to obtain root privilege on Android devices if the Android devices haven't been rooted yet (i.e., there is no su)?

Comment: How did you got the App to use the "android.ui.system"? Because i'm getting errors when i add it to my manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Though you have added System userId in the manifest file, the root access is not granded. There are additional checks like Signature match check.

Comment: yeah,that's right.Signature checking is required.I've made that checking passed by exploiting 'Master Key' bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html)...

You should be able to easily achieve root privilege by implementing the code from that link.

Thanks to Muzikant for the blog.

Comment: thanks. Muzikant provide a wrap class to execute su command to require root privilege temporary. That's not what I exactly means.Because the pre condition is that there is no su(bin) command.Putting a su(bin) to /system/bin/ is what I expect  to do.